# Delete a row which holds primary key and that primary key is an input from user

Tags: mysql

I have a few records.For example,

```
    id   username        email
    1      abc        abc@yahoo.com
    2      pqr        pqr@gmail.com
```

'id' is primary key in the above table. I want to take input as 'id' from user and check if a record exists belonging to 'id' and then delete that corresponding row/record. I know that I have to use select and delete together but haven't got correct query yet.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, my friend? Looking for a [**delete query**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) with `where` clause?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to do a select.  You could just do the delete and check the number of rows affected.

Comment: delete from mytable where id="something"

Comment: A side note: do I get that right: you allow the _user_ to chose what numerical `id` is used for him inside your database model?

Comment: @arkascha I'd hope in this case, by user, he means administrator.

Comment: @RagingBull I tried,                                             string squery = " delete from  informationtable.informationdata where id='" + this.idtext.Text + "';";                                              (Where idtext is the text field )But it doesn't look for the key in the table to check if it exists. I want to first check if it's present,if present then delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

First, [SQL DELETE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) is used to delete entries from table based on certain condition, here in you case its **id** column, your sql will look somewhat like:

DELETE FROM <your_table_name> WHERE ID= <user_entered_id_value>

But **id** in table is often used as a Primary Key and is kept unique, which is not exposed to the users at all.

Comment: Yes, I tried using this query but it won't give work for the record which is not present in the table. It works only if that record is present in the table,what if the record is not present?

Comment: @user3482658 If the record is present, 1 row will be affected.  If the record isn't present the 0 rows will be affected.  It seems pretty simple to me, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `informationtable` is the table name, try this:

```
string squery = "delete from informationtable where id=" + this.idtext.Text + ";";
```